# ng-view not fetching my template Angular 1.6.2

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

```
  TFC.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/bookings', {
    templateUrl: '/mybookings.html',
    controller: 'accountCtrl'
  })
  .when('/credits', {
    templateUrl: '/mycredits.html',
    controller: 'myCreditsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/membership', {
    templateUrl: 'membership.html',
    controller: 'membershipCtrl'
  })
  .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    controller: 'profileCtrl'
  })
  .when('/invoices', {
    templateUrl: 'invoice.html',
    controller: 'invoiceCtrl'
  })
  .when('/team', {
    templateUrl: 'team.html',
    controller: 'teamCtrl'
  })
  .when('/benefits', {
    templateUrl: 'benefits.html',
    controller: 'benefitsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/refer', {
    templateUrl: 'refer.html',
    controller: 'referCtrl'
  })
  .when('/support', {
    templateUrl: 'support.html',
    controller: 'supportCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'accountabout.html',
    controller: 'accountAboutCtrl'
  })
})
```

and this my html in which I am injecting views

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TFC">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Founder's Cafe</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section style="background: black;">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="position: static;">
            <div class="navigation-wrapper">
                <a href="/" class="custom-logo"><img src="assets/img/webLogo.png" alt="TFC Logo"></a>
                <ul class="custom-navbar nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="about-link active"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-links">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/facility.html" class="nav-links">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pricing.html" class="nav-links">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/event.html" class="nav-links">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/gallery.html" class="nav-links">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg navbar-btn" name="button">LOGIN</button></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="ham-wrapper">
                    <div class="hambar-1"></div>
                    <div class="hambar-2"></div>
                    <div class="hambar-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 35em; overflow: hidden; background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-wallpapers-hd-8087-8418-hd-wallpapers.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed;">
            <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="account-wrapper">
            <div class="account-items">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="user-image"><img src="" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="user-header">
                        <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
                        <h4>heading</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="user-items">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-main">
                            <img src="assets/img/account/icn-booking.png" alt="">
                            <h5 class="item-name"><a href="#/bookings">My Booking</a></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-arrow"><img src="" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-main">
                        <img src="assets/img/account/icn-logout.png" alt="">
                        <h5 class="item-name"><a href="">Logout</a></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="account-display">
             <div ng-view=""></div>
         </div>
         </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/style.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the mybookings.html is in the root folder.

```
<div class="bookings-header">
  <img src="assets/img/account/icn-booking.png" alt=""><h4>My Bookings</h4>
</div>
<div class="bookings-info-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="bookings-info">
    <h5>Coworking:</h5>

    <div class="coworking-info">
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <p>Dedicated Desk(Dec 1-Dec 30)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the `ng-view` directive is inside `div.account-display` and as a test I am trying to show just the mybookings.html when user clicks on the `my bookings` list item which is inside the first `div.item` inside `div.user-items`

The ng-view isn't showing anything, nor am I getting any error. An interesting thing is that when I looked into the network tab of my dev console, mybookings.html is not mentioned in it.

My angular js and angular-route versions are 1.6.2. The jquery version is 3.1.1

Need help with this

Comment: maybe path of template is wrong. please double check.

Comment: path template is correct, it is in the root folder.

Comment: did u include the path of the controller file in the project?

Comment: @Shashank the controller is in the same app.js file

Comment: It's not even displaying the static content. I have included the mybookings.html content.

Comment: can u create a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZoCWC7qKkFYZULKWRTa4?p=preview) and it seems to working fine. If you sure the html file paths are exist then other possible downfall might be version conflict.Check the angular route and angular version is compatible with each other.

```
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Edited

Routes in Angular 1.6 need to add `!` when redirecting to state.

`<h5 class="item-name"><a href="#!/bookings">My Booking</a></h5>`

Comment: angular and angular-route versions are same 1.6.2. How do I test whether the two are compatible or not. I would have received an error in the console, if they were not compatible

Comment: i not sure how to test it. But i replicate the same example with version 1.6.2 and its not working https://plnkr.co/edit/DynazVDKOaHIX91JrGnb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you sir. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ng-view></ng-view>` tag 
instead of `<div ng-view=""></div>`

and also the default URL in route provider

```
.otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/bookings'
})
```

Comment: I have worked it with angular js a lot of times, I am not a beginner at it. Also, no your solution didn't work because it is not really a solution. Nothing is wrong with using `<div ng-view=""></div>`. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

For the `mybookings.html` file to load default, you have to specify the `default url` parameter in the `route provider`. This is the method for that. I hope this will fix your issue.

```
TFC.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/bookings', {
    templateUrl: '/mybookings.html',
    controller: 'accountCtrl'
  })
  ....
  .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/bookings'
  })
})
```

now by default `mybookings.html` will load

Comment: Please read the question details, I haven't mentioned that I am trying to load mybookings.html by default, i need it reload when the use clicks on "my bookings" list item